# objectify query object by key and property value

Tags: java, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I would like to check if a property of an object changed and only load it if so.
The solution I thought of would be 'something' like:

```
if(ofy().load().filterKey("=", myKey).filter("property =", value).count() == 0) {
    ofy().load().key(myKey);
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: And what's the problem? You've already done this with the code you posted.

Comment: thats how i would like to use the api not how it's actually possible.

Answer (score 1):

I just found out that filterKey has to be the last filter statement. eg:

```
ofy().load().filter("property =", value).filterKey("=", myKey).count()
```

is working.